# Angular FormData forEach and getAll error method in IE11

Tags: angular, methods

In Angular, I tried to loop a FormData object and this error shows in IE11.
Btw, all is working in Chrome.

```
const formData = new FormData();
// appended file here
formData.forEach((x: File) => {
  console.log(x);
});

IE11: "ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'"

IE11: "ERROR TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'getAll'"
```

Is there a way in how to properly loop this in IE11? And why does IE11 showing this error while other browsers aren't?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

browsers implement new JS features at different paces, and IE always stay behind. Now, specially with Microsoft declaring no new updates will be provided to IE browsers you will always will suffer trying to support IE versions. In this way to work with IE 11 at your angular project you need to set update some configurations to provide support for them.

at `tsconfig.json` set the target to es5:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5"
}
```

at `broswerlist` file change the line where you have `not IE 11` to `IE 11`

If further features are needed to be supported, you will need to import polyfills at `polyfills.ts` to your project works properly.